# HTML-based game: Detect collisions using jQuery 

Tags: jquery, collision-detection

I just developing a baloon game with two divs. One is moving horizontally and the other vertically.

The problem is that I am unable to trigger a function when two divs touch each other.

Comment: can you add some part of your 'moving' code ?

Answer (score 0):

create every movie parts as separate object

find the coordinates of each created object every second or some milisecond using settimeinterval

if the object coordinates are same or in boundary; destroy the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
function detectCollision(){

    //detect the top and let of balloon 1
   //detect the top and left of balloon 2
   //check if the top and left are same or in a required range
}
```

Call this function at a time interval depending on your move speed this will detect collision